# Rotate Sprite on creation.

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm pretty new to this framework and I'm having some troubles rotating an Sprite. I think I'm doing it right but somehow it's not working.

This is what I have: I'm using scene2d and I have an Actor called Cube. In the constructor of this cube I generate the texture for an sprite that is a cube doing the following:

```
public Cube(){
    sizeOfCube = 40;

    Pixmap pixmap = new Pixmap(sizeOfCube,sizeOfCube, Pixmap.Format.RGBA8888);
    pixmap.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    pixmap.fill();
    pixmap.drawRectangle(0,0,sizeOfCube,sizeOfCube);

    Texture rectangleTexture = new Texture(pixmap);
    pixmap.dispose();

    rectangleSprite = new Sprite(rectangleTexture,0,0,sizeOfCube,sizeOfCube);
    rectangleSprite.setPosition(Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2 - rectangleSprite.getWidth() / 2,
            Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2);

    rectangleSprite.setOrigin(rectangleSprite.getWidth()/2, rectangleSprite.getHeight()/2);
    rectangleSprite.rotate(45f);
}
```

In the draw method of the actor I have:

```
@Override
public void draw(Batch batch, float alpha){
    batch.draw(rectangleSprite, rectangleSprite.getX(), rectangleSprite.getY());
}
```

The Sprite is correctly rendered in the screen but there is no rotation at all! It's driving me crazy, I have read multiple places that my code seems to be fine but I can't make it work so there must be something that I'm missing as I'm completely new to this world.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should send information about rotation to batch when drawing your **Cube**:

```
@Override
public void draw(Batch batch, float alpha){
    batch.draw(rectangleSprite,
               rectangleSprite.getX(), 
               rectangleSprite.getY(),
               rectangleSprite.getOriginX(),
               rectangleSprite.getOriginY(),
               rectangleSprite.getWidth(),
               rectangleSprite.getHeight(),
               rectangleSprite.getScaleX(),
               rectangleSprite.getScaleY(),
               rectangleSprite.getRotation());
}
```

By the way you could make it shorter. Don't create new **Sprite**. Just call Cube methods (it is an actor you said): **setPosition()**, **setOrigin()**, **rotate()**. Then in render method you could use **Cube** methods like this:

```
batch.draw(rectangleSprite, getX(), getY(), getOriginX(), getOriginY(), getWidth(), getHeight(), getScaleX(), getScaleY(), getRotation());
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked perfectly! I hate being new in stuff, it's difficult to get you started!

Answer (score 1):

If you call `sprite.draw(Batch batch)` or `sprite.draw(Batch batch, float alphaModulation)`, libGDX will factor in all of your sprites properties for you, instead of you having to do them yourself with your own draw call.